# Using model.matrix with bigglm in R

Tags: r, glm, model.matrix

My specific question is why 'model.matrix()' is not working as expected with 'bigglm()'.

The same model matrix works fine in glm:

```
temp <- model.matrix(~ ORGN_FLOW_INT + work_attract + MINS, data=HTWAF_sample)
sim2 <- glm(FLOW_INT ~ temp, family=poisson(link="log"), data=HTWAF_sample)
```

This works fine.

But in 'bigglm()', the same commands receive an error:

```
temp <- model.matrix(~ ORGN_FLOW_INT + work_attract + MINS, data=HTWAF_sample)
sim2 <- bigglm(FLOW_INT ~ temp, family=poisson(link="log"), data=HTWAF_sample)

Error in model.frame.default(tt, chunk): variable lengths differ (found for 'temp')
```

More generally, I would request examples of how to use 'model.matrix()' along side lm/glm in a conceptually correct way.  I have searched for examples all over the web and read the documentation for 'model.matrix()', but I cannot seem to find quality examples of how model.matrix() should be used in conjunction with lm/glm.  My own approach above came from trial and error.

As an aside, if you would like to know why I want to use 'model.matrix()', it is because I have a factor variable with 1900 different values.

Comment: You are not supposed to use `model.matrix` directly for this. Just pass the formula `FLOW_INT ~ ORGN_FLOW_INT + work_attract + MINS` to the model function and it will call `model.matrix` internally. (However, adding 1899 variables from a factor to a model seems excessive. You should probably consider a way to reduce this number.)